# Como usar substring em React Native?

Tags: react-native

Como usar substring em React Native?

```
if (total >= 1000){
      const total2 = total.substr(total.lenght - 3, total.lenght);
      total = total2 + '.' + total.substr(total.lenght - (total.lenght - 1), total.lenght - 3);
    }
```

Erro:

> undefined is not a function (evaluating 'total.substr(total.lenght - 3, total.lenght);')

Minha intenção e verificar se o valor é maior ou igual a 1000, dividir a string em duas partes e colocar o ponto na terceira casa de trás pra frente: 1.000

Comment: `total.toString().substr(total.lenght - 3, total.lenght);` como pode ver, esta convertendo para **string** pois o método `substr` é para **string**. [String.prototype.substr()](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: Estou começando com react native, mas até onde sei, ele usa javascript e o mesmo não tem tipagem de variáveis. Minha intenção realmente é pegar o número total e tratá-lo como string. Amanhã vou tentar converter pra ver se resolve

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tem um erro de sintaxe no seu código: o correto é `length` e não `lenght` (o `h` no final).

Além de estar fazendo errado no `substr`. O erro em questão é porque a variável `total` não é uma *string*. O `substr` só irá funcionar com strings.

Converta antes a variável `total` em string com `.toString()` e depois aplique corretamente o `substr` para chegar ao resultado desejado:

```js
total = 2000;
if (total >= 1000){
   const total_string = total.toString();
   const total2 = total_string.substr(0, total_string.length - 3);
   total = total2 + '.' + total_string.substr(total_string.length - 3, total_string.length);
   alert(total);
}
```

Comment: Eu nem tinha notado que estava errado `length`.